# How do I test that I've interfaced with a mixin correctly?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mixins

How do I test that I've interfaced with a mixin correctly?

I have a mixin that provides a class method used similarly to named_scope or protected_attribute. I have tested the mixin extensively and now need to test that the model it's mixed into is using it correctly.  I don't want to test the entire mixin again, just that I've called it with the correct args.

the model:

```
class SomeClass
  include MatchMixin
  match :name
end
```

the test:

```
describe SomeClass do
  it { should be_kind_of(MatchMixin) }

  it "calls match with :name" do
    SomeClass.stubs(:match)
    SomeClass.new
    SomeClass.should have_received(:match).with(:name)  # <= this fails
  end
end
```

the mixin:

```
module MatchMixin
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def match(arg)
      # lots of awesome code
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried everything I can think of.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This sounds like you're asking for code review instead of something concrete. What you have is fine, IMO. Don't go overboard testing two lines of code that don't really include any logic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally just use your first example:

```
it "includes MatchMixin" do
  SomeClass.new.should be_a_kind_of(MatchMixin)
end
```

However, if your mixin requires some missing pieces to be filled in (i.e. requires some method definitions that it doesn't know how to implement), then you could use RSpec's [shared examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/shared-example-group).

That then means the spec code itself is written only once, but is exercised with differing inputs.

```
it_behaves_like "a MatchMixin"
```

Comment: most times I'd agree with you, my hesitation is that I can include the mixin without calling the method it provides.  The Mixin is a tool to lazily shorten urls with bitly. So when I call match (shorten) then it should create a field that holds the short url, create a private method designed to call bitly and queue a background job to shorten the url.  there's a lot going on and while I've tested the mixin itself, I don't want to have to test mixin again when I mix it in.  I just want to test that I've called the public class method correctly.

Comment: Override the method with a partial mock: `the_object_with_the_mixin.should_receive(:short_url).with("http://long-url.com/blarg").and_return("http://sho.rt/1")`